# How to change the password for file sharing in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, file-sharing

I have file sharing in Windows 10 (version-1909) working well with a password. I set the password sometime ago when there was a UserGroup option, by changing the UserGroup password. Now in recent version there is no UserGroup.Now I want to change the password for file sharing. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

The password is the same as your Windows password unless you shared a folder with a different password. If you wish to have a different password, right click on the folder or drive and go to security and sharing. Set a password on the drive or folder once sharing is on. Then users will need the drive or folder particulars and the password.

If you need to change your Windows user password, go to Start, Settings, Accounts and change the password there.

Please see the screen shot below.  Also look for other users on your system where you assigned names and passwords.

[image]

Also right click on Computer (This PC) and select Manage. Users and Groups remain there.

Comment: I couldn't find any password setting in security, sharing or any other tab in properties of the drive or folder. Please add a screenshot if possible.

Comment: Right click on the drive or folder and select Properties.  Select the Sharing Tab and then the Advanced button and look to see if these have been shared. That is where the password would be if there is one.

Comment: Please add a screenshot if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Screen shot added to the original question

Comment: But no option for password sir.

Comment: Further edit.  Windows 10 retains Users and Groups in the newest edition if you had Users and Groups before the update

Comment: @Vijay - Instead of a comment that will eventually be deleted, update your question, with a screenshot that show what options you do have.

Comment: I don't think the requested password can be found in that dialog, but there may be differences between the home and pro editions of Windows. Here is a good youtube video explaining that we need to setup a new user and use that for sharing permissions: https://youtu.be/6e6AlfP6nUc. However, in my Windows 10 Home I fail terribly, as user management seems to be something I didn't pay for :/.